# (AWS SES / Laravel) - Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I've been trying to setup mailing in Laravel 7 with AWS SES and have setup all my credentials properly and set my drivers to SES.

I get the following error when attempting to send an email verification with the default built in functionality.

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2465 (Operation timed out)

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@taxsion.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=HIDDEN
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=HIDDEN
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

I have ensured that the AWS key and secret have full access to SES, in my `config/services.php` I am setting it to use these credentials.

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
]
```

I have searched through numerous "solutions" and have tried creating a separate user for SES only with no luck.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan config:clear`? The error suggests that it's not trying to use the values you have in your `.env` as the error mentions `smtp.mailtrap.io`.

Comment: @Rwd Yes, I've ran that multiple times and have tried on both my valet server and from the `php artisan serve` command.

All give the same issue.

Comment: What do you get when you do `dd(config('mail.driver'), config('mail.host'));`

Comment: @Rwd Both return just `null`

Comment: The port is right, the protocol is right, the host is wrong. Find out where you have mailtrap configured.

Comment: Did you upgrade from an earlier version or was it a fresh install of Laravel 7?

Comment: @Rwd This is a fresh install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my `.env` was not being loaded due to caching.

Simply running `php artisan config:clear` cleared the cached config and updated it with my new parameters.

My `.env` contains the following:

```
MAIL_MAILER=ses
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 7 has introduced [Multiple Mail Drivers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/releases) which has changed how the mail config works.

If you look at your `config/mail.php` you'll notice that you have a `MAIL_MAILER` value instead of `MAIL_DRIVER`. You should be able to simply change the `MAIL_DRIVER` to `MAIL_MAILER` in your `.env` file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=ses
```

You may also need to clear the config cache after you've made the change:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: I have set that and ran `php artisan cache:clear` yet I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, the only one I have in there now is just `MAIL_MAILER=ses`

Comment: It's interesting because my `mail.mailer` is coming back as `null` still